# Series expansion of $\exp(-x)$ using powers of $\frac{1}{1+x}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

I want a power series expansion of $e^{-x}$, but since powers of x blow up as x→∞ and powers of $\frac{1}{x}$ blow up as x→0, I was wondering if a series expansion of $e^{-x}$ using powers of $\frac{1}{1+x}$exist?

Comment: No, I want an expansion of $\exp(-x)$ using powers of $\frac{1}{1+x}$, if possible.

Comment: It exists, but then it will "blow up" as $x$ to $-1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint

change variable

$$z=\frac1{1+x}$$

$$\exp(-x)=\exp(-\frac{1}{\frac{1}{1+x}}+1)=\exp(-\frac1z+1)=e\times \exp(-\frac1z)$$

Now find the Taylor expansion of $\exp(-\frac1z)$

**PS**. convergence is on your own risk. $\exp(-x)$ exists near $x=-1$ but the series will diverge.

Comment: Does $\exp(-1/z)$ have a Taylor expansion?  Near $z\to0^+$, it is smaller than any power of $z$, and near $z\to0^-$ it is larger than any power of $z$.

Comment: @ Michael you are correct. Do you believe the problem is due to $\frac1z$ or do to nature of z which can never be zero since it is equal to $\frac1{1+x}$?